# How to download satellite image from planet.com using API key

Tags: python, api, image, satellite, planet

I would like to know what to do (step by step in simple words) and how to get data from www.planet.com

There is tutorial 
https://www.planet.com/docs/api-quickstart-examples/
but anyways I have problem..

So I have API key and Trial 14 days access to the platform. I tried to use Python command line to get satellite image that I chosed, but actually I am not good at Python at all and I don't know how to build request.

`export PL_API_KEY=mykey` (does not work either)

Comment: I would suggest contacting their support/sales people directly. They are very responsive. Having also signed up for the 14-day trial, there were quite a few items that do not work during that trial period as stated. One of them is daily imagery for maritime coverage. There is only a very small piece of California on dry land that they allow access to the "Daily" imagery and it has a 2-week delay during the trial period. I am only making the assumption that this might also be affected in some way, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Python and the command line are not the same thing. That should be an environmental variable they want you to set

Comment: Thanks @StefanoPotter but actually it does not help.

Comment: @MapHound I found on their website that they check this page and search for the tag "planet" so I am trying, maybe they will see me here :)

Comment: I am using Anaconda3,how can i input the "export"(everytime when i input export in the command line,it shows that it's not valid )

Comment: [@wang dayu](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/127687/wang-dayu), you are welcomed to ask it as a new question on GIS Stack Exchange. Please be aware of the proper structure of your question. As far as I got your point, I suggest you attaching some graphics and insert some code where it says about your error message in Anaconda. Cheers.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/145439)

Answer (score 4):

You will need to have python installed to install the planet command line tool. Open up a terminal window:

**Step 1** - install planet command line tool:

```
pip install planet
```

**Step 2** - export your API key:

```
export PL_API_KEY=XXXXX
```

**Step 3** - download your image (for example a RapidEye visual product with the id "20160707_195146_1057917_RapidEye-1")

```
planet data download --item-type REOrthoTile --asset-type visual --string-in id 20160707_195146_1057917_RapidEye-1
```

**Notes:**

I like to add the `--verbose` option which provides a little more feedback of what is going on:

```
planet --verbose data download --item-type REOrthoTile --asset-type visual --string-in id 20160707_195146_1057917_RapidEye-1
```

You can skip Step 2 and alternatively provide your API key in the command itself:

```
planet --api-key XXXXXX --verbose data download --item-type REOrthoTile --asset-type visual --string-in id 20160707_195146_1057917_RapidEye-1
```

Quickstart is here: https://www.planet.com/docs/api-quickstart-examples/cli/

Restrictions because of the trial may apply, of course, as mentioned in the comments above.